# DI Registration service type .net core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0

I have one n-tier layered app and in Infrastructure module where I'm trying to develop sending email for confirmation an user, I'm getting an error.

> No service for type
>   'IMS.Infrastructure.Helpers.CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'
>   has been registered.

From code what I had did is next:

```
public class CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<TUser> : DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser> where TUser : class
{
    public CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider, IOptions<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions> options, ILogger<DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser>> logger) : base(dataProtectionProvider, options)
    {
    }
}
```

and for creating services:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationIdentityDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

            services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options =>
                {
                    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                    options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;

                    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                    options.Tokens.ProviderMap.Add("CustomEmailConfirmation",
                        new TokenProviderDescriptor(
                            typeof(CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<IdentityUser>)));

                    options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "CustomEmailConfirmation";

                })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationIdentityDbContext>();



            services.AddTransient<CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>>(o =>
            {
                var service = new CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(o.GetService<IDataProtectionProvider>(), o.GetService<IOptions<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>>(), o.GetService<ILogger<DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>>>());

                return service;
            });
```

I will need help to understand how service CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider is not registered, what I had did wrong ?

Kind Regards,
Danijel

Comment: What is relationship between `IdentityUser` and `ApplicationUser`? Take note that IoC might not be clever enough to handle generic variance. So from perspective of IoC `CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>` and `CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<IdentityUser>` are two unrelated interfaces.

Comment: ApplicationUser is inheriting IdentityUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From perspective of IoC container `CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>` and `CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<IdentityUser>` are two different and unrelated classes.

You should have both usage and registration to have same type of user.