# System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.DataProtectorTokenProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0

Stil on same project where I had issue [DI Registration service type .net core 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972242/di-registration-service-type-net-core-3-0/58973199#58973199). Now when that is fixed I'm getting new error. 
Now my code looks:

```
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationIdentityDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

    services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;

            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            options.Tokens.ProviderMap.Add("CustomEmailConfirmation",
                new TokenProviderDescriptor(
                    typeof(CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<IdentityUser>)));

            options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "CustomEmailConfirmation";

        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationIdentityDbContext>();

    services.AddTransient(o =>
    {
        var service = new CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<IdentityUser>(o.GetService<IDataProtectionProvider>(), o.GetService<IOptions<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>>(), o.GetService<ILogger<DataProtectorTokenProvider<IdentityUser>>>());

        return service;
    });
```

And error is:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.DataProtectorTokenProvider`1..ctor(Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.IDataProtectionProvider,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1)'.

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same issue and the problem is related to the packages itself.

Basically the problem was that many of those `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` packages are now moved to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` framework, so you remove your `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` reference and add this to your project:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I've noticed that my constructor (same as yours) is missing additional parameter `ILogger<DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser>>`, which you can see in .NET Core 3.* versions on this [link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.dataprotectortokenprovider-1?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: I just want to thank you for answering this question - this solution worked for me but with a caveat. My Function App was targeted for .Net Core 2.1 but my shared libraries were targeted for .Net Standard 2.0 (which should be the corresponding Core to Standard version) however this was the likely cause of the package version mismatch. Changing the class libraries to Core 2.1 and doing the steps you've outlined worked for me.. I've lived with this problem for so long, I don't know what to do now...

Comment: Minor thing that is hard to notice which makes it even more frustrating, but that's how programming works I guess

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue while creating a custom JWT provider for password reset emails. Instead of inheriting from `DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser>`, I just implemented the `IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<TUser>` interface directly. You will need to implement the `CanGenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync` method yourself but you can avoid the hacky framework reference.

From:

```
public class MyTokenProvider<TUser> 
    : DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser> where TUser : IdentityUser
```

To:

```
public class MyTokenProvider<TUser> 
    : IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<TUser> where TUser : IdentityUser
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem referencing the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` package and using the `AddJwtBearer` extension method.  Seems like verison 5.0.16 is ok,but 6.0.0, 6.0.3, and 6.0.4 are broken (didn't bother trying 6.0.1 nor 6.0.2) - they pull in an incompatible version of `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll`.  So the solution for me was to downgrade to 5.0.16